# Devise InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, csrf-protection

I am trying to create an authentication system with devise. When I try to login with a post request, without ajax, it gives me the "ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken" Error.

I've seen that this is supposed to be a common bug with devise. I've seen some usual approaches to it, which don't work for me:

- To include an csrf token on the html: It is already included in the login site
- Include a hackish solution like this: skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: -> { controller_name.include? 'sessions' }
  . Unfortunately this doesn't change a thing. In the original solution I've seen it suggested to include it into Users::SessionsController. I can change whatever I like in this controller or even delete the whole controller and it still works the same.

This is supposed to be a problem with protecting from forgery according to other sources, but I can literally remove it from the application controller and I still have the same error.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

I believe that Devise checks the token independently from the rest of my app. This would also explain why it doesn't work even though there is a token at the sign in form. I have no clue what to do about it though.

Comment: Hey James! Were you able to fix it eventually? If so, how?

Comment: Hi Michal, it's too long that I remember what solved it. I think it was some code around the authentication that caused it. Like redirects and rights. I rewrote it in cancancan and did the redirects in a more sane way and I think that was the solution to it. Try to slim down your code around authentication (only for debugging), until the error doesnt appear any more. Do you have a SO Question yourself online?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I managed to solve the problem in the meantime - in my case it was enough to prepend the call to `protect_from_forgery` so that it runs before `authenticate_user!`. I upgraded to rails 5.2 and didn't notice the warning in the documentation. So for future visitors: `protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true` in your ApplicationController does the trick.